# Change properties of JNDI retrieved datasource

Tags: java, spring, datasource, jndi

DataSource is configured at the application server (Jboss)

```
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/TestDataSource" pool-name="TestDataSource" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
                <connection-url>...</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>informix</driver>
                <new-connection-sql>set lock mode to wait 15</new-connection-sql>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>...</user-name>
                    <password>...</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>...</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                    <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                    <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                    <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
        </subsystem>
```

DataSource is retrieved using JNDI. Before returning it as a bean I would like to change the url and driver class. All other configured properties should remain unchanged. DataSource interface does not provide setters to achieve this. What is the best solution for this kind of task?

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {
@Value("${datasource.test}")
private String dataSourceProperty;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:/" + dataSourceProperty);

    // here before returning the datasource I would like to change the url and database driver, other configs should remain unchanged
    return dataSource;
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot, nor should you. The datasource is predefined in JNDI and isn't for modification afterwards.

Comment: Provide another one, or as many as you need. The whole idea to configure this stuff externally. Otherwise why use it at all?

Comment: I wanted to change the datasource to conform it to JDBC proxy driver for logging SQL (Log4jdbc-log4j2). If second datasource is defined based on the original as another JNDI resource then I need to add Log4jdbc-log4j2 as a jboss module and all logging messages reach jboss loggers instead of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the DataSource interface to the concrete implementation (e.g., org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource), then just use the setter method of the concrete class:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource tomcatDataSource = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource)dataSource;
tomcatDataSource.setUrl("...");
```